# c# - How to get sum of the values from List?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get sum of the values from list.

For example: I have 4 values in list
1 2 3 4 I want to sum these values and display it in Label

Code:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string monday;
    TextBox txtMonTot;
    List<string> monTotal = new List<string>();

    if (Application["mondayValues"] != null)
    {
        List<string> monValues = Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>;
        for (int i = 0; i <= gridActivity.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridActivity.Rows[i];
            txtMonTot = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
            monday = monValues[i];
            monTotal.Add(monday);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **list.Sum()** .

Comment: Since this comment is being upvoted, it should be mentioned that as others have commented, you need a reference to System.Linq to use list.Sum().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List of objects, how do I get the sum of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351876/c-sharp-list-of-objects-how-do-i-get-the-sum-of-a-property)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use the `Sum` function, but you'll have to convert the strings to integers, like so:

```
int total = monValues.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Comment: If they have to be summed, why are the lists of string in the first place?

Comment: You probably don't need the lambda `Sum(Convert.ToInt32)`

Comment: To clarify, @Sayse is not wrong, and the syntax is valid. The problem is Sum has two overloads, one which accepts a func that returns a decimal and one that accepts a func that returns a Nullable<decimal>. With the method group syntax, it can't tell which overload Convert.ToDecimal matches. The lambda syntax works around the problem wrapping Convert.ToDecimal in another method which always returns a decimal.

Comment: Make sure to add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Just to clarify if you are going to use the `List<T>().Sum()` method you have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code

Answer (score 18):

Use [Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909132%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
 List<string> foo = new List<string>();
 foo.Add("1");
 foo.Add("2");
 foo.Add("3");
 foo.Add("4");

 Console.Write(foo.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)));
```

Prints:

> 10

Comment: I was just about to ask the same

Comment: I really don´t see why this answer should get downvoted! Maybe he read this Question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast and applied rule no. 2

Answer (score 10):

You can use LINQ for this

```
var list = new List<int>();
var sum = list.Sum();
```

and for a List of strings like Roy Dictus said you have to convert

```
list.Sum(str => Convert.ToInt32(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
List<string> monValues = Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>;
int sum = monValues.ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32).Sum();
```