# Foreach IEnumerable reference by string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to access the contents of an IEnumerable by string rather than int.

**METHOD**

```
public List<Foo> GetFoo(IEnumerable<Bar> bar)
{
    List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();

    var query = from x in bar       
                select new Foo()
                {
                    foo = x.foo,
                    bar = x.bar
                };
    foo = query.ToList();
    return foo;
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<td>@foo["bar"].foo<td>
```

I know the above doesn't exist, but that's what i'm looking to do.  If i do `foo[0].foo` it --obviously-- works.

**EDIT**

I went with the `Dictionary<string,Foo>` approach as @D Stanley and @juharr recommended, but i still have to iterate through these results via a foreach loop in order to access the KeyValuePair.  I'm trying to bypass a foreach and access the results just via the Key.  Is this possible?

```
public Dictionary<string,Foo> GetFoo(IEnumerable<Bar> bar)
{
    var query = from x in bar               
                select new Foo()
                {
                    foo = x.foo,
                    bar = x.bar
                };
    return query.ToDictionary(f=>f.foo,f=>f);            
}
```

Comment: How are you expecting this to work? Which element of the sequence should `foo["bar"]` return?

Comment: i'm currently running a foreach within a foreach and saying `if item.foo==item2.foo then ....`.  I was trying to bypass this logic by just running 1 foreach and accessing the other IEnumerable by the item.foo.  that make sense?

Comment: Can you add the `foreach` you had to the question?

Comment: You should consider using a dictionary rather.

Comment: @jellz77: `"that make sense?"` - No, not really.

Comment: @Rahul can i store multiple values in a dictionary or just Key->Value?  I come from a PHP background so i'm really looking for a multi-dimensional array

Comment: sounds like you want a `Dictionary<string, Foo>` instead.

Comment: @jellz77 you can store multiple Key-Value pairs, but the key has to be unique and not null.

Comment: @jellz77 How would `foo["bar"].foo` work if there were multiple objects mapped to `"bar"`?  It would be a lot more clear if you wouldn't reuse the type names for variables and properties.

Comment: i think @juharr provided what i'm looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that compact with the `List` structure. It only has an indexer that accepts integers (the index of the item you want). A few options:

- Subtype `List<Foo>` to add an indexer that accepts a string
- Use a dictionary instead of a `List<Foo>`:

  ```
  public Dictionary<string,Foo> GetFoo(IEnumerable<Bar> bar)
  {
      var query = from x in bar       
                  select new Foo()
                  {
                      x.foo,
                      x.bar
                  };

      return query.ToDictionary(f => f.bar, f => f));
  }
  ```

then `foo["bar"]` will give the the `Foo` object indexed by `"bar"`.  You do not need to iterate the entire collection to find the object with the matching key.

Comment: this did it!  thanks!

Comment: the results are still being stored as ints, then the KeyValuePair?

Comment: in your example, i'd still have to iterate through the results in a foreach then access the key once in the foreach

Comment: I'm not sure what you man by either comment - a dictionary is designed for fast access by key - yes you still need to loop through if you want to iterate the keys.  Your example indicated that you wanted _a specific key_, though.

Comment: correct so ideally i want to access foo["randomString1"].someValue without the implementation of a foreach. The reason i don't want to run a foreach is because i already have multiple foreach statements in my view and am looking for fast access to a KeyValue.

Comment: What I gave you gives you fast access by key value.  I don't see where you're using `foreach` so I don't know what the problem is.  But if you think you need to iterate the entire collection to find the matching key then see my update.

Answer (score 0):

With a little more digging, i was able to find the answer through [C# List of objects, how do I get the sum of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351876/c-sharp-list-of-objects-how-do-i-get-the-sum-of-a-property)

Using my example above, i implemented the following logic using linq:

**METHOD**

```
public List<Foo> GetFoo(IEnumerable<Bar> bar)
{
    List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();

    var query = from x in bar       
                select new Foo()
                {
                    name= x.name,
                    amount = x.amount
                };
    foo = query.ToList();
    return foo;
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@double total = foo.Where(item => item.name == "jon").Sum(item => item.amount);    
<td>@total<td>
```

within my view, i'd replace "jon" with a variable to alleviate a foreach within a foreach.  sorry for the confusion all, but appreciate everyone's help!!