# C# group by list then SUM

Tags: c#, list, linq

How to group by then sum inside the list
below is my sample code:

```
List<BrandType> brandTypeList = new List<BrandType>();

BrandType brandTypeClass = new BrandType();
brandTypeClass.Amount = 100;
brandTypeClass.Count = 50;
brandTypeClass.Category = "Fish";
brandTypeList.Add(brandTypeClass);

BrandType brandTypeClass2 = new BrandType();
brandTypeClass2.Amount = 100;
brandTypeClass2.Count = 50;
brandTypeClass2.Category = "Fish";
brandTypeList.Add(brandTypeClass2);

BrandType brandTypeClass3 = new BrandType();
brandTypeClass3.Amount = 100;
brandTypeClass3.Count = 50;
brandTypeClass3.Category = "Pork";
brandTypeList.Add(brandTypeClass3);
    brandTypeList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Category }).Select
(x => new { Category = x.Key.Category, 
Amount = x.Sum(z => z.Amount), 
Count = x.Sum(z => z.Count) });
```

Here's what it looks like

```
[0] {Amount = 100, Category = "Pork", Count = 50}
[1] {Amount = 100, Category = "Fish", Count = 50}
[2] {Amount = 100, Category = "Fish", Count = 50}
```

How can I SUM the **amout** and **count** then group by Category?
I want the result to be

Amount = 200, Category = "Fish", Count = 100

Amount = 100, Category = "Pork" Count = 50

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351889/3583859 This link might be helpful

Comment: The primary cause of your issue is x => new { x.Category } inside the GroupBy call. It should just be GroupBy(x => x.Category)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet will work for you:

```
var result = from brand in brandTypeList
            group brand by brand.Category into grp
            select new
            {
                Category = grp.Key,
                Amount = grp.Sum(z => z.Amount),
                Count = grp.Sum(z => z.Count)
            };
```

This one also works fine:

```
var result = brandTypeList.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select
(y => new {
    Category = y.Key,
    Amount = y.Sum(z => z.Amount),
    Count = y.Sum(z => z.Count)
});
```

It turns out that your code also works fine, probably the problem is that you expect list to be modified inplace, but linq does not produce side effects and new IEnumerable will be created and you need to save results to variable.