# How to get the Sum of found values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to find the elements which have the OverSized value == true and sum the BoxQuantity value of them. So far I can find the first element that has the OverSized value = true and returns the BoxQuantity value of it with the code below. Is there anyway to find all the elements that matches that condition and return sum of the box quantity values?
(NOT THE SAME AS SUM AMOUNT QUESTION)

```
var boxNumBig = shippingSummary.ShippingBoxes.Find(item => item.OverSized == true);
int numofBigBox = boxNumBig.BoxQuantity;
```

Comment: You are not even using LINQ. Please read a basic tutorial before.

Comment: This question is not the same as the other one you have marked as duplicate. I have read that question before asking and it doesnt have the condition part. My Question was how to get the sum of values returned by a condition

Comment: Huh, are you **completely sure** it doesn't? Because I read this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445009/2141621 in that same post

Comment: the answer is! but not the question. duplicate questions and duplicate answers posted on different questions are not the same things. anyhow thanks for your attention.

Comment: There, I added 2 more duplicates that ask exactly for filtering plus sum.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can:

```
var summation = shippingSummary.ShippingBoxes
                               .Where(item => item.OverSized)
                               .Sum(x => x.BoxQuantity);
```

This uses the `Where` extension method to retain all the objects where the `OverSized` is `true` and then uses the `Sum` method to take the summation.

Comment: Close race.  You just got me!

Comment: Thank You very much! However to the person marked this question as duplicate the other question doesn't have condition in it.

Answer (score 0):

`.Find` is not part of LINQ. It returns the first item in the list that it matches. I think you want to use `.Where` to find all of them.