# Sum of the elements per square range of int's in List<int>

Tags: c#

My list is:

```
var list = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
};
```

Without doing

```
int sum = list[0]*list[0] + list[1]*list[1] + list[2]*list[2] + list[3]*list[3]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List of objects, how do I get the sum of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351876/c-sharp-list-of-objects-how-do-i-get-the-sum-of-a-property)

Comment: Hello, Could you add what you have tried so far? What is the exact expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = list.Sum(o => o * o);
```

Comment: do you mind explaining your answer, the OP may not have an idea what it is even doing let alone know anything about `linq` and or lambda expressions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers work as well, you should learn how to use a loop. It is a fundamental building block of programming. For example, we can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over each element in the list. see:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int val in list)
    sum += val * val;
```