# Sum all item in property

Tags: c#

I have this Class:

```
public class C1
{
    publice double[] p1 { get; set; }
}
```

And here I have instanced it in List<>

```
List<C1> clist = new List<C1>();
```

I would like to sum the item in the property `p1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# List of objects, how do I get the sum of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351876/c-sharp-list-of-objects-how-do-i-get-the-sum-of-a-property)

Comment: Do you want the sum per object `C1`, or the overall sum of all objects of type `C1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
clist.Sum(i => i.p1.Sum());
```

Comment: Hey you might not want to answer very obvious duplicates with practically a code only answer. Not my downvote but I think that's why.

Comment: @EpicKip To be fair, we still have no real dupe - although I bet there is one. Anyway I agree not to answer such questions.

Comment: @EpicKip From my perspective the dupe does not match, because of my question in the comments above - otherwise I´d had used my hammer already :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere To be honest I hadn't noticed it was an array. He can apply the dupe target answer 1 level deeper for succes though.